# How can i block HTML code in string for profile page

Tags: php, html

i've got i little question.
i'm trying to block all html code for my profile page for my website, so people cant break the whole system, and mostly so they cant put url's in their profile quote
this is my code

```
function block_html($string) {
  $find = '/\<(.*?)\>/';
  $replace = '';
  return preg_replace($find,$replace,$str);
}
```

thanks already

Comment: Consider using PHP's [filter_input()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) function.

Comment: how should i use that to block html code?

Comment: Use FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, but read the docs!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best method for sanitizing user input with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129677/whats-the-best-method-for-sanitizing-user-input-with-php)

Comment: Why recreate the wheel?